# Updateing html table with ajax and pug (jade)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am writing a site that displays the latest released comics. I have a html table that is made using pug served via express

```
table(name='releases')
 thead
  tr
    th Name
    th Publisher
   tbody
    each comic in comics
      tr
        td #{comic.title}
        td #{comic.publisher}
```

The trouble I am having is how do I update this? I already have my ajax post with the new data which is the same format as the old. But I am unsure how would I update the table with it since I can't use the pug format originally used ie `each comic in comics` would I have to convert this to JS? Or can I use the pug format?

Comment: Please search the web for "pug crud tutorial" and you will see a number of examples on how to accomplish this.  As it stands, this question is too broad for StackOverflow as it doesn't have a discrete problem statement with sample code and it can't be answered without multiple paragraphs of explanation and code samples..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update pug variables through ajax. One possible way to update the table is to append the new data to the table using id in ajax